# Oracle ASM vs RAID 10

Tags: oracle-asm, raid

I have oracle ASM 11gR2 on oracle linux 5.8 and i want to install oracle database.
I have some disks and i want to use the redundancy strategies of oracle ASM or RAID 10 .
I do not know which one is better ? Oracle ASM redundancy or RAID 10 ?

Comment: It is not a question of one over the other. Take a look [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9402230) (and follow the [link](https://community.oracle.com/message/9381973#9381973)) for a discussion of the possible options of the combinations between the two.

Comment: What does RAID10 mean? Do you have a storage box that can provide RAID10? Or do you want lvm to create RAID10 volumes?

Answer (score -1):

If you can afford RAID, then go for it.. RAID or no RAID depends.. if your hardware provides redundancy then go with ASM and mirror it as you wish.
Tom Kyte has brilliant insight towards this..try visiting his site as well.